# Is it possible to have an APEX Testmethod to see SOME, but not ALL data?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, customsetting, seealldata

Usually I only need `@isTest(SeeAllData=false)`

But now I need to see some Custom Settings (they count as "data", too). And at the same time I must ensure to see only the Custom Settings, but NOTHING else in the database.

As far as I have understood [the documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm), this is not possible.

I need a trick / workaround/ hack to have some queries WITH data and some other queries WITHOUT data. Can this achieved? I accept "dirty", "hackish" and "inofficial" solutions, too, if necessary. Clean approaches preferred.

**Background**

It does not make sense to mock the Custom Settings up, because it is a re-usable logic shared between different Orgs driven by these settings. Settings and code are heavily coupled. Basically the combination of Code and Settings create some generic SObjects which are fed automatically and dynamically into generic test classes to get some basic code coverage without writing a single line of code. To help the automatics to do well, I need to provide some meta-information (for scope, irregularities, ...). I used a separate APEX class for that until I recently moved to Custom Settings. They bring greater flexibility. Only in Test-Context they are EMPTY. At the same time, I need the rest of the database to be EMPTY.

Also I can't hardcode the Settings into the apex code in any way. The code has fallback mechanisms to do something even if the settings are completely missing or wrong. So I need to query for the settings with dynamic SOQL as far as I know. The compiler not allowed see the settings-name and couple things up.

I could use a static resource instead of the custom setting to hold the meta-information, but I don't want to.

For now I want only to find out, if a selective SEE and NOT SEE data is feasible in any way.

Comment: Can you insert custom setting based on org? Lets say if your custom setting is org dependent, then just insert it based on OrgId (As org id wont change). Wont that work?

Comment: Have you not considered `Custom Metadata` instead?

Comment: @AdrianLarson not yet. Thanks for your hint, I will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to store configurations in a way that is visible to tests, `Custom Metadata` seems like a more appropriate tool for the job. Since it is metadata rather than data, tests will have no problem seeing the values. That does mean you will lack control over what configuration your test runs under, unless you use dependency injection to swap out query results.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No. You either get see no data (good) or see all data (makes codey cry.)

As others have stated here Custom metadata is a better fit than custom settings for this kind of work. However, I think the *best* option is to dependency inject a class that is quiddity aware so that you can either query for real custom metadata records, or generate test specific data. Your method should be capable of returning a List that your code and your tests can both rely on to return the data needed.

Comment: I don't quite follow, what does quiddity have to do with injection?

Comment: Adrian, yeah, that came out weird. You can either inspect the quiddity and basically swap out the results, but if you write a DI ‘d class you could just mock it. Two separate ideas.